# "ctype" functions from <locale> throw an std::bad_cast

Tags: c++, locale, facet, libstdc++

This program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>

int main () {
    std::isxdigit(std::cin.peek(), std::cin.getloc());
}
```

throws an exception of type `std::bad_cast` on me  when compiled with gcc or clang using libstdc++. It runs normally with VS2010.

I understand what's going on here. `peek()` returns an `int` to accommodate the out-of-band EOF value. The locales are not required to have `ctype<int>` facet (they do have this facet in VS, perhaps as an extension). If the locale has no facet to perform a function, it will throw a `bad_cast`.

But shouldn't this be working according to the spirit of the original `<ctype.h>`? Is this a defect in the standard? Is there a commonly-accepted workaround? I know I can check for EOF myself and cast to the relevant character type, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: The character type has to be known (assume a 32 bit int is a character type having a 64 bit representation for EOF). It can not be resolved, a locale is not bounded to a specific character type, but it's facets are.

Having:

```
std::isxdigit<char>(std::cin.peek(), std::cin.getloc());
```

will clarify the call and (!) ignore EOF making it char(int(-1)).

Hence you might check for EOF yourself.

Comment: There used to be an idiom of using `ctype` functions with EOF. I understand why the idiom is not working in the locale-land. I'm asking whether the standard committee members knew what they where doing when they broke it, and whether they or anyone else thought of an alternative. The solution of wrapping these functions with an EOF checker doesn't strike me as particularly elegant. If everyone needs these functions wrapped, why the wrapped versions are not a part of the standard?